# How can I add a constraint to an Oracle table to make sure, each row in the table is referenced at least once in another table?

Tags: oracle, constraints

In my oracle DB i have table A that is referenced through its ID column in table B. Though, currently, not every row of A is referenced in B. I would like to add a contraint of sorts or a virtual column to A that ensures that for EVERY row in A there is at least one row in table B or, in other words, every table A row is referenced by at least one row in table B. But i don't know how to go about it. i thought about doing a deferrable virtual column in table A like in this pseudo code here:

```
alter table A add (b_id as (
    case select id into b_id from the first row of B that references A
        END) unique deferrable initially deferred);
```

but this doesn't make sense to me and, i'm not even sure if it is at all possible to reference another table in the virtual column of a table. i feel like, as a newbie, there might be some better options out there. how would you go about it, any ideas?

Comment: You don't want to do this. You're trying to create a circular dependency, which won't be possible with a FK between the child and parent. Instead, catch and report this after the fact as a report/alert, rather than try to prevent it initially. You *can* enforce this with deferred constraints and messy, unmanageable code, but it isn't a path you want to go down. It is perfectly normal for a parent table to have rows that no child references.

Comment: @PaulW, I'm aware of the circular dependency and don't feel great about it. But there has to be a one to many relationship between the rows of tables A and B. each row of A has to be referenced in at least one Table B row. Is there a way to achieve this with a constraint and without table A referencing table B?

Comment: You *might* be able to have a materialized view that has an outer join between the parent and child tables and counts the matching rows, with a constraint for that being greater than zero, but it's still messy and I'm not sure it would quite do what you want.

Comment: @AlexPoole, thank you. how would you go about it? Say you have a persons table and bankaccounts table. and each person should have at least one bank account, which is currently not the case. how would you approach this?

Comment: If you insert a parent row into A and then child row(s) into B all at the same time (same transaction), you can create two deferred FKs in both directions, insert the parent, insert the child(ren), then update the parent row with one of the child PKs and then commit. Eek.. not good modeling. If I were you I wouldn't try to enforce the rule that a parent has to have at least one child. it's normal in data modeling to depict this (cross vs. circle behind the crowsfoot) but not normal to enforce it with constraints in an RDBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a parent-child relational where every parent has (at least) one child then you can create a deferrable foreign key from the parent back to the child:

```
create table employees ( 
  employee_id   int primary key,
  first_name    varchar2(100) not null, 
  last_name     varchar2(100) not null, 
  department_id int not null
);
  
create table departments ( 
  department_id   int primary key, 
  department_name varchar2(30) not null, 
  manager_id      int not null
);

alter table employees
  add constraint empl_department_fk
  foreign key ( department_id )
  references departments;
  
alter table departments
  add constraint dept_manager_fk
  foreign key ( manager_id )
  references employees ( employee_id )
  deferrable;

/* Delay deferrable constraint validation */
alter session set constraints = deferred;

insert into departments ( department_id, department_name, manager_id )
values ( 42, 'Test dept', 42 );

/* Constraint is validated here - raise error & rollback */
commit;
--ORA-02291: integrity constraint (CHRIS.DEPT_MANAGER_FK) violated - parent key not found

insert into departments ( department_id, department_name, manager_id )
values ( 42, 'Test dept', 42 );

insert into employees ( employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_id )
values ( 42, 'Tess', 'Ting', 42 );

commit;
```

You can use this whenever each parent row has a default/primary/owner row from the child rows. This is more common than often assumed - e.g. Every department must have a manager, every customer must have a default payment method, every person must have a primary contact method.

If there is no default/primary/owner, you can enforce this by creating a `fast refresh on commit` materialized view with a query outer joining the child to the parent. Add a (deferrable) not null constraint over child columns in the MV and voila:

```
create materialized view log on employees
  with rowid, primary key ( department_id ),
  sequence
  including new values;
  
create materialized view log on departments
  with rowid, primary key, 
  sequence
  including new values;

/* 
  Is there a dept with no employees?
  MV outer joining child to parent 
*/
create materialized view department_employees_mv
  refresh fast on commit
as
  select e.rowid empl_rid, d.rowid dept_rid,
         e.employee_id, d.department_id
  from   employees e, departments d
  where  d.department_id = e.department_id (+);

/* Check child columns are not null */
alter table department_employees_mv 
  modify employee_id 
    constraint deem_employee_nn
    not null
    deferrable;
    
/* Prove MV works - drop dept -> emp FK */
alter table departments
  drop constraint dept_manager_fk;

/* Add new dept with no employees */
insert into departments ( department_id, department_name, manager_id )
values ( 99, 'test', 99 );

/* MV query - note employee_id is null */
select e.employee_id, d.department_id
from   employees e, departments d
where  d.department_id = e.department_id (+)
and    d.department_id = 99;

EMPLOYEE_ID DEPARTMENT_ID
----------- -------------
<null>                 99

commit;
--ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
--ORA-02290: check constraint (CHRIS.DEEM_EMPLOYEE_NN) violated

/* Insert rolled back */
select e.employee_id, d.department_id
from   employees e, departments d
where  d.department_id = e.department_id (+)
and    d.department_id = 99;

insert into departments ( department_id, department_name, manager_id )
values ( 99, 'test', 99 );

insert into employees ( employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_id )
values ( 99, 'Tess', 'Ting', 99 );

commit;

select * from department_employees_mv
where  department_id = 99;

EMPL_RID           DEPT_RID           EMPLOYEE_ID DEPARTMENT_ID
------------------ ------------------ ----------- -------------
AAAToCAAPAAAANHAAB AAAToEAAPAAAAMPAAB          99            99
```

For more on this see my recent Ask TOM Office Hours on [Advanced Database Constraints](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?oh=19984).